# Function to return duplicates words if they are repeated >= n times

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a function to return words if they are repeated a certain amount of times(n).

```py
def repeat_word_count(text, n):
    counts ={}
    for text in text.split():
        if text in counts:
            counts[text] += 1
        else:
            counts[text] = 1
            
    return [counts for counts in counts if counts.values() >= int(n)]
print(repeat_word_count("buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo", 2))
```

Above is the function when executed returns an attribute error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "program.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(repeat_word_count("one one was a racehorse two two was one too", 3))
  File "program.py", line 9, in repeat_word_count
    return [counts for counts in counts if counts.values() >= int(n)]
  File "program.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    return [counts for counts in counts if counts.values() >= int(n)]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Collections Counter function to do this:

```
from collections import Counter

def repeat_word_count(text, n):
    counter = Counter(text.split())
    return [{k: counter for k, counter in counter.items() if counter >= n}]


print(repeat_word_count("buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo", 2)) #[{'buffalo': 4}]
print(repeat_word_count("buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo", 5)) #[{}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think one of the problems of your code is that you're reusing the `counts` variable in the iteration of the `counts` collection.

After you fix it, the next error is that you're comparing a collection `counts.values()` with an int `n`.

I think you can get a better and simpler solution leveraging the `Counter` collection.

```
from collections import Counter

def repeat_word_count(text, n):
    counts = Counter(text.split(' '))
    return [word for word in counts if counts[word] >= int(n)]

print(repeat_word_count("buffalo buffalo test test2 test2 buffalo buffalo", 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the list comprehension line:

```
return [counts for counts in counts if counts.values() >= int(n)]
```

You are reassigning counts. You also have the `counts.values()` in the wrong place in the list comprehension.

Just correcting your code, it should be something like:

```
return [count for count in counts.values() if count >= int(n)]
```

However that is just going to return the counts, not the words. If you want the words you need something like this:

```
return [word for word, count in counts.items() if count >= int(n)]
```

Personally I would also handle the checking and counting a bit differently. Some would suggest a slightly more 'pythonic' way of handling the checking of the dict entries and incrementing them would be using a try/except, like this:

```
def repeat_word_count(text, n):

    counts ={}
    for text in text.split():
        try:
            counts[text] += 1
        except KeyError:
            counts[text] = 1

    return [word for word, count in counts.items() if count >= int(n)]

print(repeat_word_count("buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo", 2))
```

The reasoning behind this is that in the case where you find it in the dict, you only have to look it up once and then increment it. That is instead of looking in the dict to see if it is there and then if it is there looking it up again in the dict to increment the entry. With the try/except approach, when it fails to find it in the dictionary it takes the KeyError exception and adds the entry to the dict with the initial value of 1.